# Projectiles Lagging, Not Fully Being Deleted

Tags: c#, list, object, xna, projectile

For me this bug is game breaking, I am using four different Lists that control rockets that shoot out of many launchers. The launchers are also held in a list:

```
        Launchers = new List<Launcher>();
        RocketsUp = new List<Rectangle>();
        RocketsDown = new List<Rectangle>();
        RocketsLeft = new List<Rectangle>();
        RocketsRight = new List<Rectangle>();
```

If you just want to see the full thing **[Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!q5RxxKRS!aOc2E2FusBFhO_hTN-Aerd-INZySyM-qlrwZ_43Zafw)** is the project. (Please Understand that it's a compleat mess, I am trying to make it work, if I had more time then 3 to 4 weeks to finish this I would try and make it more cleaned up)

**Questions**

The Rockets will shoot out but the right rockets are stopping at random intervals, up, down, and left are work fine, how?

If I let the game play a little it starts to slow down after a while, I had thought that I had to many rockets in game firing but they're firing and being destroyed so shouldn't the game work fine since the rockets are being cleared as fast as there being spawned?

**End Questions**

Note: (I have multiple levels and when I jump to the next the lag goes away since I have a clear all in a method):

```
        Launchers.Clear();
        RocketsUp.Clear();
        RocketsDown.Clear();
        RocketsRight.Clear();
        RocketsLeft.Clear();
```

What these launchers will do is fire a projectile every set amount of seconds in a strait line until they make contact with a block or player.

I have a foreach loop go through each launcher position and spawn a rocket based on what direction the launcher is facing, 1 = Up, 2 = Down, 3 = Right, 4 = Left:

```
        foreach (Launcher l in Launchers)
        {
            l.Updata(gameTime);

            if (rocketTime > rocketMax)
            {
                if (l.Direction == 1)
                    RocketsUp.Add(new Rectangle((int)l.Position.X + 11, (int)l.Position.Y, 9, 18));

                if (l.Direction == 2)
                    RocketsDown.Add(new Rectangle((int)l.Position.X + 11, (int)l.Position.Y, 9, 18));

                if (l.Direction == 3)
                    RocketsRight.Add(new Rectangle((int)l.Position.X, (int)l.Position.Y + 11, 18, 9));

                if (l.Direction == 4)
                    RocketsLeft.Add(new Rectangle((int)l.Position.X, (int)l.Position.Y + 11, 18, 9));

            }
        }
```

Then a for loop is called for each rocket list and define their size since the texture is not the correct size:

```
        if (rocketTime > rocketMax)
            rocketTime = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsUp.Count; i++)
        {
            RocketsUp[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsUp[i].X, RocketsUp[i].Y - 3, RocketsUp[i].Width, RocketsUp[i].Height);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsDown.Count; i++)
        {
            RocketsDown[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsDown[i].X, RocketsDown[i].Y + 3, RocketsDown[i].Width, RocketsDown[i].Height);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
        {
            RocketsRight[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsRight[i].X + 3, RocketsRight[i].Y, RocketsRight[i].Width, RocketsRight[i].Height);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
        {
            RocketsLeft[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsLeft[i].X - 3, RocketsLeft[i].Y, RocketsLeft[i].Width, RocketsLeft[i].Height);
        }
```

Then the rockets are drawn in the Draw method:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsUp.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rocketUp, new Rectangle(RocketsUp[i].X,
                RocketsUp[i].Y,
                RocketsUp[i].Width,
                RocketsUp[i].Height),
                Color.White);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsDown.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rocketDown, new Rectangle(RocketsDown[i].X,
                RocketsDown[i].Y, 
                RocketsDown[i].Width, 
                RocketsDown[i].Height), 
                Color.White);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsRight.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rocketRight, new Rectangle(RocketsRight[i].X, RocketsRight[i].Y, RocketsRight[i].Width, RocketsRight[i].Height), Color.White);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rocketLeft, new Rectangle(RocketsLeft[i].X, RocketsLeft[i].Y, RocketsLeft[i].Width, RocketsLeft[i].Height), Color.White);
        }
```

Finally the Rockets are called in another class called Block:

```
    public Player BlockCollision(Player player, GameTime gameTime, Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;
        kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        Rectangle BlockRectangle = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);

        Rectangle top = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y - 10, Texture.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + 5, (int)Position.Y + Texture.Height, Texture.Width - 10, 10);
        Rectangle left = new Rectangle((int)Position.X - 10, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Texture.Height - 10);
        Rectangle right = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + Texture.Width, (int)Position.Y + 5, 10, Texture.Height - 10);

        Rectangle personRectangle = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Texture.Width, player.Texture.Height);

        for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsDown.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsDown[i].X, game1.RocketsDown[i].Y);

            if (personRectangle.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketDown.Width, game1.rocketDown.Height)))
            {
                player.Dead = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsUp.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsUp[i].X, game1.RocketsUp[i].Y);

            if (personRectangle.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketUp.Width, game1.rocketUp.Height)))
            {
                player.Dead = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsLeft[i].X, game1.RocketsLeft[i].Y);

            if (personRectangle.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketLeft.Width, game1.rocketLeft.Height)))
            {
                player.Dead = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsRight.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsRight[i].X, game1.RocketsRight[i].Y);

            if (personRectangle.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketRight.Width, game1.rocketRight.Height)))
            {
                player.Dead = true;
            }
        }

        if (BlockState > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsDown.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsDown[i].X, game1.RocketsDown[i].Y);

                if (top.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketDown.Width, game1.rocketDown.Height)))
                {
                    game1.RocketsDown.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsUp.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsUp[i].X, game1.RocketsUp[i].Y);

                if (bottom.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketUp.Width, game1.rocketUp.Height)))
                {
                    game1.RocketsUp.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsLeft[i].X, game1.RocketsLeft[i].Y);

                if (right.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketLeft.Width, game1.rocketLeft.Height)))
                {
                    game1.RocketsLeft.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < game1.RocketsRight.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 Rocket = new Vector2(game1.RocketsRight[i].X, game1.RocketsRight[i].Y);

                if (left.Intersects(new Rectangle((int)Rocket.X, (int)Rocket.Y, game1.rocketRight.Width, game1.rocketRight.Height)))
                {
                    game1.RocketsRight.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code is a refactorer's dream.

Comment: Not sure how this is done in gaming, but in WinForms or WPF you would use several threads: one for UI and others to do calculations. The other threads would post updates to UI, but perform work elsewhere.

Comment: Not trying to be rude or anything, but Jon is right... For the love of god, please refactor some of that code x) Other than that, looks good as far as I can tell. You get the basics of how 2D games works.

Comment: @Jon Thank you I don't even try, I have tried multiple times to refactor the code but I run into one thing that makes me stop and think that finding the error would take to long and come back to this piece of crap.

Comment: @RyanFoy It is fine considering you are learning the ropes at the moment.  Keep coding, and keep learning.

Comment: Thank you for that moral support haha. Also I have a new question, I bet you will love it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
    {
        RocketsRight[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsRight[i].X + 3, RocketsRight[i].Y, RocketsRight[i].Width, RocketsRight[i].Height);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < RocketsLeft.Count; i++)
    {
        RocketsLeft[i] = new Rectangle(RocketsLeft[i].X - 3, RocketsLeft[i].Y, RocketsLeft[i].Width, RocketsLeft[i].Height);
    }
```

You have used RocketLeft.Count where you should have used RocketRight.

Edit: Also, try disposing your 'destroyed' rockets using Rectangle.Dispose(). It may help to free up some resources.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct I had looked all over, I just can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @RyanFoy No problem, its easy to miss things like that, please mark its as the answer or vote up if it helped :)

Comment: sometimes all it takes is a little glance from a 3rd party. Your brain reads whats your intentions were as opposed to what you actually typed.